# How can i share location of every user to its nearby users within specified range e.g within 5 km? using socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io, geolocation

Assume users 'a', 'b', 'c' joined the socket.

Now suppose user 'b' is 3km away from user 'a'. and 7km from user 'c'.
so in this case user 'b' should only emit its location to user 'a' as it is within 5km range.
Also at the same time if user 'a' is 2km away from user 'c' then a should emit its location to both user 'b' and 'c' ans they are in range of 5km.

how can i implement this using NodeJs and Socket.io.

Every user which is connected to socket should emit its location to only users within 5km range.

I read that we can use haversine formulae to calculate distances between two coordinates.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.